# How do I set up services and controllers to communicate effectively?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a search and filter application for rooms. The user is able to search for a room name (e.g. Conference Room 101) and also able to add filters to narrow down their search (e.g. capacity = 6). I am trying to figure out a good solution of how to setup my services and controllers and have come up with the following solution:

[image: Visio Diagram]

The filterService gets updated by the filterCtrl through the UI and broadcasts('run:search'). This then triggers the searchResultsCtrl to ask searchResultsService for updated searchResults. The same process happens when the user types into the search field (searchFieldCtrl is updated, then updates searchFieldService).

Once searchResultsService receives the request, it gets all the rooms from roomService, applies the filters using applyFilters inside filterService, then gets the searchField and filters out the remaining rooms.

Is this a good solution using broadcasts or is there a better solution that I am missing?

Edit: I've added a workflow diagram for the filters. The same workflow happens for searchField but updates searchFieldCtrl and searchFieldService.

[image: Workflow]

Comment: Generally the recommended Angular design is UI communication should occur through a controller (*or directives but not applicable in this scenario*). I would not recommend any direct coupling between a service and the UI, there is also a reason why you can't instantiate a Service in the UI (html) like you can a controller.

Comment: All these services except roomService have an accompanying controller that then calls its respective service to update filters/search field

Comment: That is not very clear. If you want to show communication between types you should use a behavioral diagram, not a compositional diagram (*which is what this appears to be*).  A sequence diagram would illustrate your proposed solution much more clearly.

Comment: I just attached a workflow diagram showing the steps. Hope that is a little more clear

Comment: Why not use a [facade pattern](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=facade%20pattern)? Have a single service that coordinates those efforts with the other services and have the controller call into that service. It would be easier to test (*write unit test code for*) and you would not have to broadcast anything.

Comment: Great idea! How do I let the controller know that the results have been updated then? Would I place a $watch on that the facade's results variable?

Comment: Pass in a call back as a parameter or have the service return a promise.

Comment: Could you attach a sample solution? I don't understand how the searchResultsCtrl would use a callback or promise in this situation since other controllers are updating the searchResultsService

Comment: @Passersby has this been solved or are you still trying to find the best architecture?

Comment: I ended up $watching the searchService.getSearchResults() in the necessary controllers. The filterService would call the searchService and update the search results would trigger the controllers $watches